# Count of unique values by groupby in two columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, unique

I want to determine the `count` of `unique` values based off two `columns` in a `pandas` `df`.

Below is an example:

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'B' : ['08:00:00','John','08:10:00','Gary','08:41:42','John','08:50:00','John', '09:00:00', 'Gary','09:15:00','John','09:21:00','Gary','09:30:00','Gary','09:40:00','Gary'],
    'C' : ['1','1','1','1','1','1','2','2','2', '2','2','2','3','3','3', '3','3','3'],           
    'A' : ['Stop','','Res','','Start','','Stop','','Res','','Start','','Stop','','Res','','Start','']
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Output:

```
        A         B  C
0    Stop  08:00:00  1
1              John  1
2     Res  08:10:00  1
3              Gary  1
4   Start  08:41:42  1
5              John  1
6    Stop  08:50:00  2
7              John  2
8     Res  09:00:00  2
9              Gary  2
10  Start  09:15:00  2
11             John  2
12   Stop  09:21:00  3
13             Gary  3
14    Res  09:30:00  3
15             Gary  3
16  Start  09:40:00  3
17             Gary  3
```

If I perform the count based of `Column A` and `C` I return the following:

```
k = df.groupby('A').C.nunique()

Res      3
Start    3
Stop     3
```

I'm hoping to split those up based on the people in `Column B`. So the intended output would be:

```
John Stop  2
     Res   0 #Nan
     Start 2

Gary Stop  1
     Res   3 
     Start 1
```

I have tried `k = df.groupby('A').B.C.nunique()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

we can create a flattened DF:

```
In [34]: d = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((df.iloc[::2], df.iloc[1::2, [0]])), columns=['time','id','op','name'])

In [35]: d
Out[35]:
       time id     op  name
0  08:00:00  1   Stop  John
1  08:10:00  1    Res  Gary
2  08:41:42  1  Start  John
3  08:50:00  2   Stop  John
4  09:00:00  2    Res  Gary
5  09:15:00  2  Start  John
6  09:21:00  3   Stop  Gary
7  09:30:00  3    Res  Gary
8  09:40:00  3  Start  Gary
```

prepare a multi-index, which will include all combinations:

```
In [36]: idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((d.name.unique(), d.op.unique()))
```

and group by two columns:

```
In [39]: res = d.groupby(['name','op'])['id'].count().reindex(idx, fill_value=0)

In [40]: res
Out[40]:
John  Stop     2
      Res      0
      Start    2
Gary  Stop     1
      Res      3
      Start    1
Name: id, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a strange dataframe, would strongly advice to not have times and names in the same column. Just add another column! This will make things easier.

Given your data, if you don't mind `RES`missing from John:

```
df[df==''] = None
df = df.fillna(method='ffill')
df[df['B'].isin(['Gary', 'John'])].groupby(['B', 'A']).C.nunique()
```